# How can I obtain the selected dates from a DateRangePicker

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have created a DateRangePicker using Kotlin Jetpack Compose. How can I obtain the selected dates so that I can use them in my code? I would like to assign them to periodStart and periodEnd variables.

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.CalendarLocale
import androidx.compose.material3.DatePickerDialog
import androidx.compose.material3.DateRangePicker
import androidx.compose.material3.DateRangePickerState
import androidx.compose.material3.DisplayMode
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextButton
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.alele.datepickertemplate.ui.theme.DatePickerTemplateTheme
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneId

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun DatePickerTemplate(){

    var showDatePicker by remember {mutableStateOf(false)}
    val periodEnd by remember {mutableStateOf(LocalDateTime.now())}
    var periodStart by remember {mutableStateOf(LocalDateTime.now())}

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
    ){
        Button(onClick = { showDatePicker = true }) {
            Text(text = "From $periodStart")
        }

        Button(onClick = { showDatePicker = true }) {
            Text(text = "To $periodEnd")
        }

        if(showDatePicker) {
            DatePickerDialog(
                onDismissRequest = {showDatePicker = false},
                confirmButton = {
                    TextButton(onClick = {showDatePicker = false})
                    {Text("Ok")}
                },
                dismissButton = {
                    TextButton(onClick = {showDatePicker = false})
                    {Text("Cancel")}
                }
            ) {
                DateRangePicker(
                    state = DateRangePickerState(
                        initialSelectedStartDateMillis = null,
                        initialDisplayedMonthMillis = null,
                        yearRange = 2023..2023,
                        initialDisplayMode = DisplayMode.Picker,
                        locale = CalendarLocale("UK")
                    ),
                )

            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to get the 2 selected dates and assign to the periodStart and periodEnd variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rememberDateRangePickerState()` to store the date range picker state and use it to get the selected dates.

**`rememberDateRangePickerState()`**

```
val state = rememberDateRangePickerState(
    initialSelectedStartDateMillis = null,
    initialDisplayedMonthMillis = null,
    yearRange = 2023..2023,
    initialDisplayMode = DisplayMode.Picker,
)
```

**Usage**

```
DateRangePicker(state = state)
```

**To get selected From date** - `state.selectedStartDateMillis`
**To get selected To date** - `state.selectedEndDateMillis`

[Docs reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#DateRangePicker(androidx.compose.material3.DateRangePickerState,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.DatePickerFormatter,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.material3.DatePickerColors))

---

Sample

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun DatePickerSample() {
    var showDatePicker by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val state = rememberDateRangePickerState(
        initialSelectedStartDateMillis = null,
        initialDisplayedMonthMillis = null,
        yearRange = 2023..2023,
        initialDisplayMode = DisplayMode.Picker,
    )

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = { showDatePicker = true },
        ) {
            Text(text = "From ${state.selectedStartDateMillis}")
        }
        Button(
            onClick = { showDatePicker = true },
        ) {
            Text(text = "To ${state.selectedEndDateMillis}")
        }
        if (showDatePicker) {
            DatePickerDialog(
                onDismissRequest = { showDatePicker = false },
                confirmButton = {
                    TextButton(
                        onClick = { showDatePicker = false },
                    ) {
                        Text("Ok")
                    }
                },
                dismissButton = {
                    TextButton(
                        onClick = { showDatePicker = false },
                    ) {
                        Text("Cancel")
                    }
                }
            ) {
                DateRangePicker(
                    state = state,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```